# How can I use awk to extract URL's from a HTML file?

Tags: awk, html

I have an HTML file with javascript and CSS in the source. Listed in the JS is a series of URLs' embedded with other meta-data. I want to use awk to extract the URLs (all enclosed in double quotes with the http:// prefix) and dump the urls to stdout. But I do not know how to use awk, but it seems to be the tool to use.

```
{
title: "Dsssat",
artist: "cxpl djij awsoj e",
mp3: "http://somesite.com/seal/dsssat.mp3",
},
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `grep`.  To include the double quotes:

```
grep -o '"http://[^"]*"' myfile.html
```

To exclude the double quotes:

```
grep -o 'http://[^"]*' myfile.html
```

**Edit**

You may want to do some further filtering to ensure that you only match the URLs in the JavaScript objects:

```
grep -o 'mp3: "http://[^"]*"' myfile.html | grep -o '"http://[^"]*"'

grep -o 'mp3: "http://[^"]*"' myfile.html | grep -o 'http://[^"]*'
```

Answer (score 10):

Why use awk? `sed` is better at this:

```
sed -ne 's/.*\(http[^"]*\).*/\1/p' < foo.js
```

Comment: awk = typically used as a data extraction
sed = stream editor, which an apply transformation

Comment: Now, how do I use curl to grab each one?

Comment: I'd say perl is more commonly used for data extraction, awk is getting increasingly rare :)

Comment: sed -ne 's/.*\(http[^"]*\).*/\1/p' < foo.js | xargs curl

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento Note that this only extracts the last URL of each line. This may or may not matter depending on your file format.

Comment: So I should spend more time on perl than sed/awk?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. If you want to learn scripting on linux, then yes: focus on languages like perl and python. sed and awk are nice for oneliners but not for bigger tasks.