# Bash script to get all mp3 file from a html page

Tags: bash, html, mp3

I was thinking in a way to get `.mp3` files from a html page, manually i did get using `wget`

```
wget http://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/wp-content/uploads/files/question-prix.mp3
```

So, i try this for an automatic way to get all mp3 file

```
grep -i -E -o "content="http://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/wp-content/uploads/files/*.mp3" "$thread" | sed 's/ /_/g' - > "$names"
```

where "`$thread`" is the name of the html file, "`$names`" is the list of filenames as output.

And

```
sed -ne 's/.*\(http[^"]*\).*/\1/p' < "$thread"
```

### related

[Bash script to extract some information from Ebay HTML pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261046/bash-script-to-extract-some-information-from-ebay-html-pages)

[How can I use awk to extract URL's from a HTML file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56675/how-can-i-use-awk-to-extract-urls-from-a-html-file)

[bash - extract filenames from html file containing multiple links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144069/bash-extract-filenames-from-html-file-containing-multiple-links)

Answer (score 2):

The following script will download every `.mp3` link in the HTML file or URL contained in the variable `$thread`.  It makes use of `lynx -dump -listonly`, which is one of the easiest and most convenient ways for a shell script to extract a list of URLs from a HTML file or URL.

The script requires you to know the URL for the index page which lists the `.mp3` files.  Or the filename containing an already-downloaded copy of that page.

You didn't mention what that index URL was, so i've just used the bogus `http://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/mp3-list.html` as an example.   Replace with the correct URL or filename.

```bash
#! /bin/bash

thread='http://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/mp3-list.html'
#thread='mp3-list.html'

while IFS= read -r url ; do
  wget "$url"
done < <(lynx -dump -listonly "$thread" | awk '/\.mp3$/ {print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wget`'s [recursive retrieval options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Retrieval-Options). For example:

```
$ wget \
    -e robots=off \
    --accept '*.mp3' \
    --level=1 \
    --recursive \
    --no-directories \
    "${thread}"
```